# handle 2 different error response for success and failer retrofit2

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

My current success response is this:

```
{"status":"success","message":"msg here"}
```

with code 200

And my error response is this:

```
{"status":"failure","message":"There was a validation error","errors":{"shippingAddress":{"phoneNumber":"Please enter a valid phone number"}}}
```

with code 400

my problem is the code below is not working because it always go inside onFailure()

```
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            // do something

        } else if (response.code() == 400) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ErrorPhone message = null;
            if (response.errorBody() != null) {
                message = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().charStream(), ErrorPhone.class);
            }
            if (message != null) {
                Toast.makeText(context, message.getErrors().getShippingAddress().getPhoneNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                String errors = "";
                try {
                    JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                    errors = jObjError.getJSONObject("errors").getJSONObject("shippingAddress").getString("phoneNumber");
                } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (!errors.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, errors, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
```

and inside onFailure i cant listen to errorBody to handle the response

Comment: Retrofit Only go inside the onFailure  when their is an error on API Call otherwise it would go there.

Comment: Fix your api, this code will work

Comment: If this work let me know.

Comment: api call seems fine because when i send correct data it return right response, and in debug i can see the error body but i cant let it go inside onSuccess

Comment: @ahmadbajwa maybe because  Call<UpdateResponse> call and the response body is not the same

Comment: Hossam Use Retrofit interface called onResponse and place your code there.

Comment: because your request or your body for get this is not correct ... you should try your onsuccess() method retrofit trigger

Comment: @ahmadbajwa yes it worked when i changed model response with the error response since im not using anything from success anyway except the error code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Retrofit** interface called `onResponse` and place your **code** there. As **Retrofit** uses two different `callback` methods for the two possible outcomes of a network requests: either a **failure** or a **successful** request. Retrofit will call the appropriate callback method depending on the result. If the request was successful, Retrofit will also pass you the response of the server.

For more view this link:https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Callback.html and https://futurestud.io/tutorials/java-basics-for-retrofit-callbacks that will help you more to learn about retrofit `Call-backs`